# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

```
The above error occurred in the <div> component:

    at div
    at App
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import LeftMenu from './components/LeftMenu';
import RightMenu from './components/RightMenu';
import MainContainer from './components/MainContainer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <LeftMenu/>
      <MainContainer/>
      <RightMenu/>

    <div className='background'>Hello</div>    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

The page is blank showing nothing I expected the background image to be displayed.

Comment: The files you show look correct. I would check the files for LeftMenu, RightMenu, and MainContainer. You probably forgot to `export default NameOfComponent` in one of those files.

Comment: https://replit.com/@AYUSHACHARYA3/Clone?v=1     If someone can help me with this too.

Comment: Hi @AYUSHACHARYA, sorry but your repl doesn't run. You have issues like file named `SideOption` but you import is `SidebarOption`. I couldn't reproduce the issue from the title